# I need to make woocommerce work in multi-currency

Tags: woocommerce

our bank just accept specific currency but I need to make woocommerce work in multi-currency

can any body help me to get the total amount in the main currency ?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've solved this is to use a currency converter plugin that only converts prices visually, ie it doesn't change the amount charged (which is in the shop currency). Customers can see indicative prices in their currency, and a warning is given that purchase / invoice will depend on their bank / card provider.

I've used this plugin but it's a bit buggy, so I had to apply my own bug fixes: https://woocommerce.com/products/currency-converter-widget/

The way the plugin works is to visually change what is displayed; but the underlying value remains unchanged. So a product worth £10 showing as €12 will be charged at £10.